# httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler); returns a large size txt file. How to read it line by line?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

For now my code looks like this - `String response = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);`
The response is so huge that the console keeps running and then it crashes. I want to buffer it, like few lines at a time, if relevant then ok else discard and read next set of lines. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

[`ResponseHandler`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/ResponseHandler.html) → [`HttpResponse`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true) → [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) → `InputStream` → `BufferedReader` → `readLine()`.

Don't forget to [consume](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) `InputStream` when you done with it.